# Using static field from C++ class in ObjectiveC code

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, memory-management, ios4

I have part of my code written in C++ and I would like to use this code from within ObjectiveC code. In the C++ code I have a class with a static fields. In ObjC code I set these fields and try to read them later. However, when I read the values of these fields I get some rubbish.

The code looks more less like this,
in one class I have:

```
   CCommunication::portNumber = 7777; //some value
```

later in another class I have:

```
int portNo = CCommunication::portNumber; //and here I get some rubbish values
```

To make this even stranger sometimes when I run the same code on my iPhone connected to my Mac it works well and when I run this code on the iPhone not connected to the Mac the code works like broken.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should define public accessors in the class CCommunication that will return these static values, then you should be able to call those accessors from within an objective-c class, as long as that class is implemented within an objective-c++ file (*.mm).